# a simple question about conditiona probability

Tags: probability, bayesian

known conditions:

$$
P(b|a) = 0.6 \\
P(c|b) = 0.8 \\ 
P(c|\neg b) = 0.7
$$

What I want to solve:

$$P(b\cup c|a )$$

(in the condition of "a" happen, at least one of b and c happen. )

I tried to break it up into:

$$P(b|a) + P(c|a) - P(bc|a)$$

but the final part  $$P(bc|a)$$ stuck me so long ...

Comment: Is it determined by the data?  What is $P(c\,|\,a)$ for instance?

Comment: There is not enough information to find $P(b\cup c |a)$.

Comment: @lulu not from data, it's just a test of mine = =

Comment: By "data" I meant the three facts you provided.  As I say, I don't even think $p(c\,|\,a)$ is determined by them.